# Is it okay If I do partition on my external Hard disk?

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have 1Tb hard disk NTFS file system 5400 rpm.If i choose to partition my hard disk, Is it going to decrease my hard disk performance?how? I have partitioned my hard disk into 3 parts(250,250,430) What you all suggests?

Comment: Having multiple partitions does not provide a peformance increase or decrease.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you just to keep a single 1T partition.

The only reason I can think of to use partitions is so you can make sure data you need fast is written on the inner sectors of the disk. This would give you a theoretical (marginal) performance boost. However, this comes at the price of not being flexible in using your disk. Especially in external disks, you want to be as flexible as possible, because you might need to use it to transfer specific types of data (big homevideos or disk images).

It'd be a shame if you create partitions and later find out that you need to remove partitions because you cannot transfer some files.

Comment: But i think it will be helpful if i accidently lost my files,there are great chances to recover.What do you think about this?

Comment: I partition my disk to use it on MAC and Windows, because MAC can't write to NTFS. So one smaller FAT32 and one large NTFS partition.

Comment: @EnisP.Aginić: there are tools available to mount NTFS volumes on Mac. Snow Leopard even has built-in support, which you can access with [this tool](http://ntfs-mounter.en.softonic.com/mac).

Comment: @VijayPandey: It depends on how you lose your files. Admittedly a file recovery program would complete faster if your filesystem was corrupted, because the filesystem is smaller. However, personally I still don't think this outweighs the flexibility you lose when creating multiple partitions. Ultimately it's up to you.

Comment: The chances of recovery would neither increase or decrease if you partition a hdd.

Comment: @Ramhound It depends on the type of failure. If the disk fails, it obviously doesn't make a difference. However, if there is corruption on the filesystem only the partition with that particular filesystem would be affected.

Comment: @mtak - My only response to that statement is that a filesystem does not become corrupt without a reason.  You are indeed right though.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine.
Theoretically, your disk now starts filling up from 3 positions on the platters outwards (or was it inwards?), instead of from one position, so the disk heads have to travel farther on average, and it will slightly increase seek time.
Practically, you won't notice it. (Although you don't say for what purpose you made those partitions...) The advantage that you gain from having those partitions will outweigh the minute time difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real speed difference between having one partition oppsed to having 3 partitions. The movement of the head as being suggested here is so slim that you will not notice it.

There won't be any speed advantage either if you would create a software raid spanning these partitions as all operations are still to the same physical disk.

Several partitions can be useful because you automatically get driveletters, but it requires managing your space better. If you don't have to, I would suggest not to.